# How to move row based on a value to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to **find & move** a row based on the value in `cStatus`.

- If the value is "Done", then move to Sheet4.
- If the value is "On-going", then move to Sheet2.
- If the value is "", then stay to the current sheet.

The code I have won't come up with any error messages, but it also won't execute the code.

Note that the code isn't my own.

```vb
Sub MoveBasedOnValue2()

    Dim cStatus As Range, wsDest As Worksheet, Keywords As Range
    Dim Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range
      
    Set cStatus = Sheet1.Range("N2")
    
    If Not cStatus Is Nothing Then
    'Do While Len(cStatus.Value) > 0
        Select Case LCase(cStatus.Value)
            Case "Done": Set wsDest = Sheet4
            Case "On-going": Set wsDest = Sheet2
            Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing 
        End Select
        
        If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
               cStatus.EntireRow.Range("A2:N2").Cut _
               Destination:=wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    End If

    If cStatus Is Nothing Then
        Set cStatus = Sheet1.Range("N1:N1000").Find(what:="Done, On-going")
   
        Do While Len(cStatus.Value) > 0
            Select Case LCase(cStatus.Value)
                Case "done": Set wsDest = Sheet4
                Case "on-going": Set wsDest = Sheet2
                Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing
            End Select
            
            If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
                cStatus.EntireRow.Cut _
                Destination:=wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `LCase` converts to lower-case but "Done" is not lower case. Why do you repeat a large block of code? `cStatus` is not Nothing as you define it at the start.

Comment: You actually have it right in the second block.

Comment: `Set cStatus = Sheet1.Range("N1:N1000").Find(what:="Done, On-going")` - this looks suspicious. When using `Find`, always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters. Also are you looking for either `Done` or `On-going`? That line of code specifically looks for "Done, On-going".

Comment: `Do While Len(cStatus.Value) > 0`... you don't need a loop at all. If the previous `Find` found a cell, then it's impossible for its `.Value` to have a length of 0.

Comment: @BigBen - I don't think that bit of code can ever run, can it?

Comment: THough obviously agree with that you say.

Comment: @SJR - not sure I follow. Are you referencing the commented-out line in the first blocK? I was referencing the loop in the second block. EDIT: Ah, I think you're referring to `If cStatus Is Nothing Then`. Agreed.

Comment: @BigBen - just because `cStatus` is never going to be Nothing.

Comment: Yep, I figured out what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not moving many rows then simply scan up the sheet checking the relevant cell value.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveBasedOnValue2()

    Const COL_STATUS = "N"

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set wsSrc = Sheet1
    With wsSrc
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_STATUS).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    
            Select Case LCase(Trim(.Cells(i, COL_STATUS)))
               Case "done": Set wsDest = Sheet4
               Case "on-going": Set wsDest = Sheet2
               Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing
            End Select
        
            If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then
               .Rows(i).Cut _
               Destination:=wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
               .Rows(i).Delete
               n = n + 1
            End If
        
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows moved", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
   
End Sub
```